# Do the Clifford Algebra products $e_1e_0$, $e_1e_{-1}$ and $e_0e_{-1}$ anticommute?

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

In a Clifford Algebra $\mathbb{CL}_{(1,1,1)}$ we have the following relations:

$e_1^2=1$
$e_{-1}^2=-1$
$e_0^2=0$

Question:
Do all the products $e_ie_j=-e_je_i$ anticommute? If so, why?

$\\ % blank space$

We know that for versors $e_1,e_2$ squaring to $1$, the following condition is sufficient to ensure $vv=|v|^2$ when the product of vectors preserves the distributive property over addition:

$e_1e_2=-e_2e_1$

This means that for any vector $v=ae_1+b_2e_2$ the following equation holds:

$vv=a^2e_1^2+b^2e_2^2+ab(e_1e_2+e_2e_1)=a^2+b^2=|v|^2$

Similarly, for $v=ae_{-1}+be_{-2}$ to get $vv=-|v|^2$, is enough to have $e_{-i}e_{-j}=-e_{-j}e_{-i}$

$vv = a^2e_{-1}^2 + b^2e_{-2}^2 + ab(e_{-1}e_{-2} + e_{-2}e_{-1}) = -a^2 - b^2 = -|v|^2$

and for $v=ae_0+be_{0'}$ if $e_{0}e_{0'}=-e_{0'}e_{0}$ then

$vv=a^20+b^20+ab(e_{0}e_{0'}+e_{0'}e_{0})=0$

Can the same line of thought be used to determine whether the products $e_1e_0$, $e_1e_{-1}$ or $e_0e_{-1}$, anticommute? If so, what are the geometric interpretations of these products?

I am aware that different conventions may lead to different applications. However, I am not familiar with any map of conventions $\rightarrow$ applications.
I read Geometric Algebra, which only hands down the case where $vv=|v|^2$.

Comment: I thought it became definitional for the Clifford algebras that the product of any two basis elements anti-commute.  But the origins indeed come from the place that we want $vv=|v|^2$

Comment: Instead of $|v|^2$, in general you have a quadratic form $Q(v)$, or equivalently a bilinear form $B(v,v)$. By definition, $Cl(1,1,1)$ is based on the quadratic form $$\vec v=x\vec e_1+y\vec e_2+z\vec e_3$$ $$\mapsto Q(\vec v)=+x^2-y^2+0z^2.$$ Yes, your approach can be used to show that $$e_1^2=+1,\quad e_2^2=-1,\quad e_3^2=0,$$ $$e_1e_2+e_2e_1=e_1e_3+e_3e_1=e_2e_3+e_3e_2=0.$$ The interpretation of $e_1e_2$ is still the $x,y$ plane.

Comment: Specifically, if you take for example $x=0,y=1,z=0$, then the equation $\vec v\vec v=Q(\vec v)$ is just saying that $\vec e_2\vec e_2=+(0)^2-(1)^2+0(0)^2=-1$. If you take $x=0,y=1,z=1$, then $\vec v\vec v=Q(\vec v)$ is saying that $\vec e_2\vec e_2+\vec e_2\vec e_3+\vec e_3\vec e_2+\vec e_3\vec e_3=+(0)^2-(1)^2+0(1)^2=-1$.

Comment: @mr_e_man Hello: judging from the size and content of these comments it is apparent you would be able to form a solution. Please consider doing this!

Comment: No. Since $e_2e_2=-1$ and $e_3e_3=0$, it means that $e_3e_2=-e_2e_3$.